# declaring basic data types in c++ using cin and cout

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdio>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

    int a;
    long b;
    char z;
    float c;
    double d;

    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
    cin>>z;
    cin>>c;
    cin>>d;

    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<z<<endl;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    cout<<d<<endl;

    // Complete the code.

    return 0;
    }
```

In the above program I think I have done everything correct , but when I am giving the input like this for example:

```
368252310 27547295356575738 c 46866.250 -247884.497885257
```

the output should display the same numbers but it is not doing so. It is displaying some other numbers
so, guys please help me out I am new to programming.

Comment: do `std::cout << std::sizeof(long);` and let us know what that is.  It is likely that `27547295356575738` is way too big for `b`.

Comment: Please show us the expected and actual output. Besides the problem with `sizeof(long)` possible being 32, are you sure that the `double` type can store the input you give?

Comment: not space hit enter after every input.

Comment: @MofiqulIslm All you need is whitspace.  space and enter will behave the same here.

Comment: @MofiqulIslm That doesn't matter, since `cin` ignores whitespace, so it would be the same thing as a newline

Comment: @NathanOliver yes you are right but​ some compilers has issue. I faced it once wiyh a online compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver  output when i have compiled
368252310
2147483647

3.74122e+033
1.97115e+266

Comment: You probably want to change the floating point display precision on cout: `#include <limits> ... int precision = numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10;
cout << setprecision(precision) << ...;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude output when i have compiled
368252310
2147483647

3.74122e+033
1.97115e+266

Answer (score 1):

You get output like this:

```
368252310
27547295356575738
c
46866.2
-247884
```

You need to do 2 changes to get same (but not exact equal) output.
Firstly, replace `'\n'` to space.
Secondly, set precision for `cout`.

```
cout<<a<<' ';
cout<<b<<' ';
cout<<z<<' ';
cout.precision(16);
cout<<c<<' ';
cout.precision(16);
cout<<d<<endl;
```

And you will get output like this:

```
368252310 27547295356575738 c 46866.25 -247884.497885257
```

It is because default precision is lower than your input.

But there is exist some number that give different output because precision of `double` is finite and last zeroes after floating point do not showed by default (and don't saved).
If you need get EXACT same output, than you should save strings, not integer or float values.
And you can try to output with option "fixed": `cout << fixed << c << ' ';`